# Cannot store aws-glue script in an S3 Bucket that has encryption policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

Can we store the aws-glue scripts in S3 Bucket with AES encryption ?

We have bucket policies that enforce AES encryption .. cannot upload files unless they are encrypted.

When creating a simple aws-glue job,  I cannot seem to save the script in a bucket with encryption.

```
{
  "service": "Amazon S3",
  "statusCode": 403,
  "errorCode": "AccessDenied",
  "requestId": "2...3B",
  "errorMessage": "Access Denied",
  "type": "AwsServiceError"
}
```

I confirmed access to the bucket by removing the bucket policy and the script can be saved.

Our standard is to enforce S3 Server Side Encryption.  is there a way to save have the script encrypted when saved?

[Script Library server side encryption option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnbDT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon just added a feature to S3 that [encrypts all objects by default](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-encryption-security-features/). So you don't have to use the policy to force clients to specify the encryption anymore.